# Represent an int as 2 bytes in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need to represent a value of 0xFF00 as two bytes (in Java). I am trying to do it like this:

```
int val = 0xFF00;
bytearray[0] = (byte)((val >> 8) & 0xFF);
bytearray[1] = (byte)((val >> 0) & 0xFF);
```

I know that byte in Java can hold values 0-255. So I expect the first array element to have a value of 255 and the second element to be zero. But what I am getting instead is -1 and 0. What I am doing wrong? What this -1 value mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Byte in java is from `-128` to `127`, not from `0` to `255`

`-1` is `1111 1111` in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_Complement) binary, equal to `255` in unsigned byte.

You aren't doing anything wrong, you just need to know that if you see `-1`, it means the byte is representing the bits `1111 1111`.

Comment: @ Esailija: Thank you! You see my problem is that a specific protocol (Modbus) requires me to include this value of FF 00 to my byte request but it doesn't accept -1 value that results from my shifting operations :) Is there any way for me to represent this value as an unsigned byte? Thanks!

Comment: @IgorAtman the problem has to be elsewhere, if you write raw byte with value of `-1` into a file, that file will then contain `0xFF`